# Iterating over loops with LoopInfoWrapperPass in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api, llvm-4.0

I am using the LoopInfoWrapperPass to generate Loopinfo, but then I am not able to use Loopinfo to iterate over the loops in my function.

Here is the code. I get a build error while using the 'make' command:

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Analysis/LoopInfo.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/InstIterator.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace {
    struct SkeletonPass : public FunctionPass {
        static char ID;
        SkeletonPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

        void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
            AU.setPreservesCFG();
            AU.addRequired<LoopInfoWrapperPass>();
        }

        virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
            LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>().getLoopInfo();
            for(LoopInfo::iterator i = LI.begin(), e=LI.end(); i != e; ++i) {
                // Some code here
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a stray error '\342' in the program at the line with the *for* loop. What is the problem?

Comment: This does not looks like C ... C is not C++. Also please indent your code properly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What do you mean you are unable to use `LoopInfo`? It seems ok to me. You need to do stuff in the body of the `for` loop, for example: `(*i)->print(llvm::outs(), 0);`. Otherwise it doesn't do much.

Comment: I am unable to compile it it gives me the following error

Comment: /home/jaswinder/Music/llvm-pass-skeleton-master/skeleton/Skeleton.cpp:24:7: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
    "code"   for (LoopInfo::iterator i = LI.begin(), e = LI.end(); i != e; ++i) { "code" 
       ^
/home/jaswinder/Music/llvm-pass-skeleton-master/skeleton/Skeleton.cpp:24:7: error: stray ‘\200’ in program

Comment: basically I am getting stray error near the for loop statement and the code does not compile   thanks in advance

Comment: Note: Revision 2 (2017-04-25, the same day the question was posted) wasn't an appropriate change. It ***removed the characters that caused the error*** (*"stray error '\342'"*).

Comment: From revision 1: One culprit is 342 200 251 (octal) → 0xE2 0x80 0xA9 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+2029 ([PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). It can be searched for by regular expression `\x{2029}`.

Comment: The full error information wasn't supplied with the question. It was probably "`error: stray ‘\342’ in program. error: stray ‘\200’ in program. error: stray ‘\251’ in program.`" (one character gives rise to ***three errors*** because it is a UTF-8 sequence of three bytes).

Comment: My guess is that the code was copied [through a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67179052/how-can-i-copy-c-code-from-a-pdf-file-to-the-codeblocks-ide/67179336#comment134218740_67179336). The pattern of weird characters looks like it (an irregular sequence of weird characters and normal space characters interspersed).

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Have you copy-pasted the *for* loop line? This might be causing the issue. If so, delete and add back the letter that is causing the issue.

Comment: There were 13 of those letters ([U+2029](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613206/iterating-over-loops-with-loopinfowrapperpass-in-llvm#comment134219501_43613206)).